# JavaScript Сортировка Списка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно отсортировать список, через js/jquery, с использованием 1 селектора ul.

Есть такой код, Задача состоит в том что, тэг 'ul' один, и нужно как-то отсортировать эти списки по значению внутри li, то есть нажал на кнопку от большого к меньшему - они поменялись местами, если нажал от меньшего к большому то поменялись местами обратно.

Есть ли подобное решение на js, либо какой материал почитать чтобы реализовать?

```
<div role="content" class="ui-content  my-listview clinics-listview">
    <ul id="list" data-role="" data-inset="true" class="clinics-list" >
        <li>2.5</li>
        <li>5.9</li>
        <li>1.5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Получаете все `li`, сортируя с помощью `.sort()` вытягиваете их значения и вставляете отсортированый список в этот `ul`. Все.

```js
$('#sort-asc').click(function() {
  sort(true);
});
$('#sort-desc').click(function() {
  sort(false);
});

function sort(isAscSorting) {
  let selectList = $('#list li');

  selectList.sort(function(a, b) {
    let aValue = +a.innerText;
    let bValue = +b.innerText;

    return isAscSorting ?
      aValue > bValue :
      aValue < bValue;
  });

  $('#list').html(selectList);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="sort-asc">Asc</button>
<button id="sort-desc">Desc</button>
<ul id="list">
  <li>2.5</li>
  <li>5.9</li>
  <li>1.5</li>
</ul>
```